# Convert VOIP notification payload to string

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to debug VOIP notifications in my app and can't use developer mode for debugging. When I get the notification I have to call my VOIP client with caller details and info. How can I convert this data into a string, something similar to what `JSON.stringify` does in javascript ? Here's my code

```
// Handle incoming pushes
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(PKPushType)type withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion {
  // Process the received push
  [RNVoipPushNotificationManager didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:payload forType:(NSString *)type];

  // Need to extract caller name and other details from VOIP notification payload to store into handle and callerName
  // Maybe can convert payload to string and assigning it to handle for checking it's structure

  NSString *handle = @"ateev"; // hardcoded
  NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
  NSString *callerName = @"ateev"; // hardcoded
  // NSString *handle = @"caller number here";

  [RNCallKeep reportNewIncomingCall: uuid
                             handle: handle
                         handleType: @"generic"
                           hasVideo: NO
                localizedCallerName: callerName
                    supportsHolding: YES
                       supportsDTMF: YES
                   supportsGrouping: YES
                 supportsUngrouping: YES
                        fromPushKit: YES
                            payload: nil
              withCompletionHandler: completion];
  completion();
}
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"Paylaod dict: %@", [payload dictionaryPayload]);` gives what? I guess you can retrieve the value you want from that. Like `NSString *handle = [payload dictionaryPayload]["handle"];` etc. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit?language=objc